# Removing all traces of old domain from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

To prepare for an upcoming college course that I might take, I have re-purposed one of my computers as an all-round network server (domain, DNS, IIS, Hyper-V et al.). When I set up the machine, I initially set it up the domain as home.local but after I added all of the roles I realized that I actually had a spare domain name that I wasn't using. I somehow managed to change the domain from home.local to home.mysite.com and everything thing seems to be working. The only problem is that when I click on AD Certificate Services from the Server Manager I get an error message, titled "Certificate Templates", with the text "Windows encountered problems enumerating writable domain controllers for the home.local Domain. This computer is not joined to a domain. Certificate templates are not available." What's funny is that I am joined to the domain and other computers on my network are too. How can I fix this issue and eradicate all traces of the old domain? Do I have to re-install Windows?

P.S. I tried Googling this error and found nothing useful or relevant. I also removed and re-installed the offending role with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you set up the Domain Controller role with the old name, you are probably best off starting over.  You can rename the domain using rendom, but the process is such a pain that it's much easier to restart from scratch unless you'd lose critical data.

Comment: "rendom" sounds familiar...I think that is what I used. I prefer not to start over if I can avoid it.